# Cpu speed slowing down occasionally

Tags: laptop, processor

I have an intel i7 8th gen cpu with 1.8 - 3.6 GHz cpu frequency.
I haven't managed to boost my cpu frequency to the 3.6 max, so it usually tops at 1.78 - 1.9 GHz.
I have noticed that, for no apparent reason, my computer starts slowing down and when I look at the task manager it says that my frequency is 0.40 GHz.
Most of the time my cpu doesn't overheat when it slows down, it just starts to slow down for a few minutes and then goes back to the 1.78 GHz limit.

Any of you could tell me what could be the cause of that, and how do I solve it?

(I have already set in the power settings to run on 100%)

also, if any one could tell me how to I do the Boost frequency thing, it'll be much appreciated :)

Comment: What brand is your laptop or desktop? This matters on how you get the boost frequency

Answer (score 1):

The GPU is probably thermal throttling, even if it doesn't seem hot or the CPU doesn't need to use all 1.8GHz of power so it slows itself and just uses what it needs. I would make sure that the fan intake/outtakes are clear and not blocked. You can also open up the computer and take a can of compressed air and blow out the fans.

To get the boost frequency, shut the computer down and restart it, as it is booting press F12 (that is the common key to get into the BIOS, but it can be a different F# key). In the BIOS you can find the Intel Turbo Boost feature somewhere, it depends on what your brand of computer or motherboard.

Just letting you know, that this is off-topic for hardware recommendations, unless if you are asking for a way to cool your computer better. I believe this fits better in 'Super User'